# How to find the android appID to use it for Admob on Corona

Tags: android, admob, coronasdk

I include this plugin on the setttings based on the documentation:

```
plugins =
        {
                ["CoronaProvider.ads.admob"] =
                {
                        -- required
                        publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
                },
        },
```

and then in my application I have

```
ads.init( "admob", "ca-app-pub-8145556512349498/5075330363", adListener )
ads.show( "banner", { x=0, y=0 } )
```

where `ca-app-pub-8145556512349498/5075330363` is the Ad unit ID from Admob site, but I suppose is not correct, because this field should be the appId, how can I found this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make your app-site in the console then hit the manage site button next to your app in the console then you get the publisher ID that refers to the Ad_Unit_id